# Connection to IaaS DB via ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have an Azure IaaS database from which we want to copy data via ADF.
For that we are currently using Self hosted IR but since the DB is hosted on an Azure VM itself isn't it possible to directly communicate between ADF and IaaS DB with out IR(By whitelisting some IP or opening some port)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should open some port, otherwise the self-hosted integration runtime can't access the Azure SQL database directly.
According to this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/c8b15f1a-8dee-4431-9c0b-eeabcf6c2930/how-to-connect-with-adf-to-sql-server-on-azure-vm?forum=AzureDataFactory), if your firewall does not allow outbound port 1433. In this case, you can use a [staged copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#staged-copy) to Azure SQL Database. In this scenario, you would require only HTTPS (port 443) for the data movement.